# problem when booting linux server : Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, system-recovery

By mistake, I executed these commands :

```
sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh
sudo ln -sf bash /bin/bash
```

When I rebooted the Linux server in recovery mode I got this message:

`init : Failed to spawn friendly-recovry pre-start process: unable to execute: Too many levels of symbolic links`

and Linux doesn't run.

Answer (score 7):

In case you don't understand this,
you have essentially destroyed your copies of `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`. 
Boot from some other medium (e.g., an optical disc, another partition, or a USB device)
and restore them from a backup (or distribution media) or the Internet.

Comment: I wonder if there is some think to do at boot setup level so solve this problem